# Using EPPlus to write to HTTP response not working

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, httpresponse, epplus

I'm writing data to Excel using the EPPlus library. I want to be able to write the fine contents in the HTTP response object and send it along such that the client would then get a file save as dialog and could choose a location to save the file.

So far, after searching a lot online, I've still had no success, heres my code snippet -

I've tried -

```
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage())
{
    //Writing data to the worksheet

    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=file.xlsx");
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";                    
    Response.BinaryWrite(package.GetAsByteArray());
    Response.End();
}
```

All the links online show the same code, but this is sill not working. There are no client side or server side errors either.

Any thoughts?

EDIT: So if this code works, there may be some problem on the client side that is calling this code? I don't have much experoence with the request response model, and there is a good chance I screwed up there.

I have made a post request which contains the contents to write to the file -

```
$post("/app/Services/ExcelDownloadHandler.ashx", { "columnValues": columnValues });
```

In ExcelDownloadHandler.ashx, I have

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var r = context.Response;
        Models.DTData excelData = (Models.DTData)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(context.Request.Form["columnValues"], typeof(Models.DTData));

        //Write excelData to worksheet using EPPlus

        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=file.xlsx");
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";                    
        Response.BinaryWrite(package.GetAsByteArray());
        Response.End();
    }
```

//Once I do a binarywrite to the response, I should be getting the File Save dialog on the browser, is that correct?

Comment: could you check what is pck.GetAsByteArray() returning ?

Comment: @AntonioBakula I've checked, it does have content, an array of a couple of thousand bytes

Comment: how does it not working ? I tried your code and it working OK, try to make a simple new project to isolate possible other problems

Comment: I just made new ASP.NET app with one button on form and this code in button onClick event : http://pastebin.com/1Sgz22ga  and it works OK

Comment: @AntonioBakula Many thanks for trying this out and confirming it works. I've edited the code to show how the client and server side both work. Since I have to format the data on the client side before sending it over, I'm not calling the code directly on any click, but issuing a post request. Could you take a look please?

Comment: Please describe how is not working, and to rule out problems with EPP try to save excel to file on server

Comment: @AntonioBakula EPP is working fine, If I give a hard-coded path on my machine, the file does get saved

Comment: did you try use another browser, maybe you have problems with your browser settings

Comment: First of all the request you did there is not a "Post-Request" but an ajax-post to an url. I guess you're trying to get the Excel-File out of your Ashx straight into your javascript code? That's not possible since javascript doesn't know the type of data you're sending. It is possible when parsing the bytestream in javascript into an excel-document ... what I highly don't recommend! Try something simpler like doing an asp-Postback!

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. Adding the four commented lines shown here made the prompt appear that allow the user to Open, Save, or Save As in IE11.
`//Write it back to the client
Response.ClearContent();      //Clear contents of current Response.
Response.BufferOutput = true; //Buffer output before sending.
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ExportData.xlsx");
Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
Response.Flush(); //Send buffered output to client.
Response.End();   //Stop rqst. process; Raise EndRequest event.`

Answer (score 0):

I using EPPLUS like bellow code:

```
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            pkg.SaveAs(ms);
            byte[] ba = ms.GetBuffer();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachement; filename=ExportData.xlsx");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", ba.Length.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(ba);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```